# Runtime error when launching the app to the physical device using Android Studio and React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I'm trying to run the app in debug mode using Android Studio but the app keeps crashing. I'm using react native.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.catholicconnect, PID: 25838
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule$1.onInitFinished(RNBranchModule.java:111)
>           at io.branch.referral.Branch.initializeSession(Branch.java:2604)
>           at io.branch.referral.Branch.initUserSessionInternal(Branch.java:1426)
>           at io.branch.referral.Branch.initSession(Branch.java:1099)
>           at io.branch.rnbranch.RNBranchModule.initSession(RNBranchModule.java:97)
>           at com.catholicconnect.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:67)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
>           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7252)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2970)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.json.JSONObject.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. Check your JSON parsing process.

Comment: I know that guys, just can't solve the issue here. Tried to fix that line of code, but can't rid the issue.